# Autostart program not working

Tags: raspbian-buster, vlc

I want to start `qjackctl` and a `vlc` media player playlist file at boot.
I’ve searched over the internet but all the options aren’t working.

I've added `@ qjackctl` at `/etc/rc.local` file, this file should be opened at boot. Nothing shows at boot.

I've also added `@ qjackctl` at `crontab - e`, but still nothing shows at boot.

Comment: please describe what you tried

Comment: Please read the text

Comment: i did read it. ... you did not describe anything ... all you said "I tried crontab, rc local and systemd" .... that does not say what you actually did

Comment: I also tried rc. `rc` -> `bash: command 'rc' not found. It can be installed with 'sudo apt install rc'`.

Comment: I've added @ qjackctl at /etc/rc.local file, this file should be opened at boot.
Nothing shows at boot.

I've added @ qjackctl at crontab - e
Nothing shows at boot. 
Cant find why it's not starting and if there is another option.

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the contents of the crontab, the rc.local and the systemd Unit file that you have tried into the question.

Answer (score 2):

You tried 3 possibilities to start **qjackctl** on boot up.

Using **/etc/rc.local**:
I cannot suggest to use it because it's deprecated and known that it has limitations due to [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/). We have seen many problems here on this site using it. Following the recommendation of the developers from **systemd** you should avoid using it.

Using **crontab**:
The entry you have given in your question cannot work. I'm not familiar with crontab but you have to prepend the entry in your crontab with `@reboot` so at least it should look something like

```
@reboot qjackctl &
```

Please note the `&` at the end. It is necessary to send the program to the background, otherwise crontab get stuck.

Using **systemd**:
For my opinion this is the best solution because you have all possibilities to adapt the service to the needed environment. You told that you have also tried **systemd** but does not show us what Unit file you used. There are many examples here on the side. You may find some on tag [systemd](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/systemd).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `@qjackctl` to `/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` and reboot. If that does not work, let me know.

Comment: There is no lxde-pi folder. Only lxpanel and lxterminal

Answer (score 1):

To start something on boot from `cron`, your contab file should read

```
@reboot <command>
```

where `<command>` is the command you want to run.